# Detect if element has focus in Angular2

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I am displaying an autocomplete dropdown for a text input using (focus)="showSearchList=true" on the input, and hiding it again using (blur)="showSearchList=false".

My problem is that if one of the results in the dropdown is clicked I want to trigger another method, but by clicking the element in the dropdown I am triggering the blur method of the input, so the dropdown results do not get clicked.  What is the best way to make this work?  I am using ES6, not Typescript, and am struggling to find anything on Google.

This is the template I have so far:

```
<div id="searchContainer">
    <input [(ngModel)]="search"
           (ngModelChange)="filterSearch()"
           (focus)="showSearchList=true;"
           (blur)="showSearchList=false"
           type="text"
           id="searchJobs"
           placeholder=" Search"/>
    <div *ngIf="showSearchList"
         id="searchDropdown">
        <p *ngFor="let result of filteredSearchResults; let index = index;"
            (click)="addResultToResults(index); search='';">
            {{result}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought instead of setting showSearchList to false on blur, I could call a method instead that checks which element has focus, and depending on that either hide the dropdown, or run my addResultToResults method and then hide the dropdown, but I have no idea how to check which element has focus in angular2.

Would love some feedback on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `mouseleave` event to control `searchlist` and move `blur` event from `input` element. And if you want to show after click items in `searchlist`, you can combine with `click` event.

**Plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CJjoxvIwonfgQM8GgFxk?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks, but for this to work the user would have to put their mouse over the dropdown first no?  So if they decide not to click on any of the results the dropdown stays there until they move their mouse over the dropdown and back out of it.

Comment: Ahhh never mind - I moved the mouseleave to the container div and it works perfectly - thankyou! :)

Comment: @user3640967  haha, you are welcome.  I'm just commenting but no need I think.

Comment: Ooops sorry - thought I had accepted it already.  Will do it now.  Thanks again!